# Serialize Cplex Concert Objects

Tags: cplex

Do the Cplex Concert objects (e.g. IloNumVar, etc.) support serialization? The documentation lists a IloCplex.Serializer class, but there are no examples of how to use it. Specifically, I'm working with the Java API, and I want to put such objects into Apache Spark distributed datasets, which require that their contents be serializable. Any insights on this question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Alex's answer: yes, the objects support serialization. The important thing is that in order to create those objects you use the `IloCplexModeler` class (a superclass of the `IloCplex` class). An instance of `IloCplexModeler` can be serialized to an `ObjectOutputStream` and can then be read back later (into an instance of `IloCplexModeler`). Then you can create a new `IloCplex` instance and use `IloCplex.setModel()` to set the deserialized model for the solver.

As Alex mentioned, you have an example for this in the `CplexServer.java` example that ships with CPLEX.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What I'm doing is a little different, but I think this should work. I want to store instances of Ilo modeling objects (IloNumVar, IloRange, etc). in an Apache Spark resilient distributed dataset (RDD). Since this data structure spans the memory spaces of multiple processor nodes, the content objects need to be serializable so that they can be transported among the nodes as transformations are applied to the dataset. I'm building the application now, so I will let you know if it's successful.

Answer (score 1):

you may have a look at the example CplexServer.java in

CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\examples\src\java

Comment: Thanks Alex. That is just what I was looking for.